# download file from web via R Console

Tags: r, download, rcurl

I'd like to download a log-file with R via a download link, but I get only the un-evaluated html.

this is what I tried, without any success:

```
url = "http://statcounter.com/p7447608/csv/download_log_file?ufrom=1323783441&uto=1323860282"

# SSL-certificate:
CAINFO = paste(system.file(package="RCurl"), "/CurlSSL/ca-bundle.crt", sep = "")

curlH = getCurlHandle(
    header = FALSE,
    verbose = TRUE,
    netrc = TRUE,
    maxredirs = as.integer(20),
    followlocation = TRUE,
    userpwd = "me:mypassw",
    ssl.verifypeer = TRUE)

setwd(tempdir())
destfile = "log.csv"
x = getBinaryURL(url, curl = curlH,
                 cainfo = CAINFO) 

shell.exec(dir())
```

Comment: This is going to be VERY hard for other folks to help you debug since we don't have your certificate needed to open the site. I'm very suspicious that the crux of your problem is the need for the cert.

Comment: You say you get "un-evaluated html".  What are you expecting?  The download from a web page usually is HTML.  If you go to that page in a browser, do you get an actual (HTML) web page or do you get a CSV file?

Comment: @Brian, with the URL the windows dialog for file-download opens..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two ways of downloading the file.

It seems when renaming the file to log.html and opening it, that we have an invalid login. This is why you get the html structure. You need to add the login credentials to the URL.

You can get the name value pairs from the html source code:

```
<label for="username2">Username:</label>
<input type="text" id="username2" name="form_user" value="" size="12" maxlength="64" class="large">
<span class="label-overlay">
<label for="password2">Password:</label>
<input type="password" name="form_pass" id="password2" value="" size="12" maxlength="64" class="large">
```

As you can see the name value pair for the username is called form_user=USERNAME and the name value pair for the password is called form_pass=PASSWORD.

This is why the curl userpwd setting doesn't work, it doesn't recognize the ids or the names.

```
 ## Url for downloading - Does not contain login credentials.
 url <- "http://statcounter.com/p7447608/csv/download_log_file?ufrom=1323783441&uto=1323860282" 

 USERNAME = 'your username'
 PASSWORD = 'your password'

 ## Url for downloading - Does contain login credentials. Use this one!! 
 url <- paste( 'http://statcounter.com/p7447608/csv/download_log_file?ufrom=1323783441&uto=1323860282&form_user=', USERNAME, '&form_pass=', PASSWORD, sep = '') 


 ## method one, using download file
 download.file(url, destfile = "log.csv" )

 csv.data <- read.csv("log.csv" )
 head(csv.data)

 ## method 2 using curl
 CAINFO = paste(system.file(package="RCurl"), "/CurlSSL/ca-bundle.crt", sep = "")

 cookie = 'cookiefile.txt'
 curlH = getCurlHandle(
 cookiefile = cookie,
 useragent =  "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en - US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6",
     header = FALSE,
     verbose = TRUE,
     netrc = TRUE,
     maxredirs = as.integer(20),
     followlocation = TRUE,
     ssl.verifypeer = TRUE)


 destfile = "log2.csv"
 content = getBinaryURL(url, curl = curlH, cainfo = CAINFO)
 ## write to file
 writeBin(content, destfile)
 ## read from binary object
 csv.data2 <- read.csv(textConnection(rawToChar(content)))
 head(csv.data2)
 csv.data2 == csv.data
```

Comment: I tried both, but neither works for me. download.file() is what I tried in the first place, without luck - I get 13k file with a CSV header and the rest is html. For the 2nd method: Firefox seems to use cookies with .sqlite ending... me:mypassw = gimoya:gimoya25

Comment: I've tested with your password. And my conclusion is that you need to change the URL from : url<-"http://statcounter.com/p7447608/csv/download_log_file?ufrom=1323783441&uto=1323860282".  To : url <-"http://statcounter.com/p7447608/csv/download_log_file?ufrom=1323783441&uto=1323860282&form_user=USERNAME&form_pass=PASSWORD". Be sure to change all your passwords, where you use this combination. Next time you want give anyone your password, send it in a message, not in a comment.

Comment: This is it! ..works fine with the extended URL - many thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to need SSL certificates etc since the url is `http:`, not `https:`... So maybe `download.file(url, "log.csv")` would work fine in this case?

I'd first make sure the url and its response is correct outside of R.

...I used Chrome to access the URL and got a downloaded file "StatCounter-Log-7447608.csv". It contains a csv header *and* HTML?!

```
"Date and Time","IP Address","IP Address Label","Browser","Version","OS","Resolution","Country","Region","City","Postal Code","ISP","Returning Count","Page URL","Page Title","Came From","SE Name","SE Host","SE Term"
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="Author" content="StatCounter">
...
```

Comment: Egad, that file is a mess.  I thought maybe there was an HTML table in there that Excel would somehow slurp out, but that isn't even the case.